# How I can develop an "xdcc send" in Java?

Tags: java, irc

I found this code to communicate with an IRC server (see below). However I did not find how to send a command to download or upload in xdcc.

Once connected to the IRC server and positioned in the channel. I want to send a command like.

**/msg bot_name xdcc send #number_of_file**

Thank you in advance for your answers, examples and help.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HackBot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // The server to connect to and our details.
        String server = "irc.freenode.net";
        String nick = "simple_bot";
        String login = "simple_bot";

        // The channel which the bot will join.
        String channel = "#irchacks";

        // Connect directly to the IRC server.
        Socket socket = new Socket(server, 6667);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream( )));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream( )));

        // Log on to the server.
        writer.write("NICK " + nick + "\r\n");
        writer.write("USER " + login + " 8 * : Java IRC Hacks Bot\r\n");
        writer.flush( );

        // Read lines from the server until it tells us we have connected.
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf("004") >= 0) {
                // We are now logged in.
                break;
            }
            else if (line.indexOf("433") >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Nickname is already in use.");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Join the channel.
        writer.write("JOIN " + channel + "\r\n");
        writer.flush( );

        // Keep reading lines from the server.
        while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
            if (line.toUpperCase( ).startsWith("PING ")) {
                // We must respond to PINGs to avoid being disconnected.
                writer.write("PONG " + line.substring(5) + "\r\n");
                writer.write("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :I got pinged!\r\n");
                writer.flush( );
            }
            else {
                // Print the raw line received by the bot.
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows only the minimum requirements needed to open a connection to a IRC server and keep it connected, actually the entire IRC protocol is much more complex and it is not implemented in the code.

The `xdcc send` is simply a normal IRC message sent privately to a specific other user (usually a bot) of the IRC server, therefore you can send it by using the command `PRIVMSG`:

```
writer.write("PRIVMSG " + botNickName + " :xdcc send #" + numberOfPack + "\r\n");
```

where `botNickName` and `numberOfPack` are two String variables containing the nickname of the bot (i.e. the recepient of the message) and the number (in string format) of the package in which you are interested.

Nevertheless you must consider that the DCC is an entire completely different protocol from the IRC protocol itself: it uses the `CTCP` message on IRC:

```
DCC SEND <filename> <ip> <port>
```

only to start a DCC session, but then there is the DCC protocol in order to manage the communication client-to-client. So if you really want to make the DCC works you should also implement it, but it would not be a quick job.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works, but as you said I can not download or upload files via the IRC protocol only. Right now I look at the Java library PircBot to send or receive files via DCC.